# 'GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Annotation set to non-printing, not permitted in PDF/A, reverting to normal PDF output'. While converting PDF to PDFA (linux))

Tags: node.js, pdf, ghostscript, pdf-conversion, pdfa

I'm using the latest version of Ghostscript "GPL Ghostscript 9.50 (2019-10-15)" but still I'm unable to convert PDF to PDF/A. The command which I used for conversion **gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile=output_filename.pdf input_filename.pdf** it is saying that *GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Annotation set to non-printing, not permitted in PDF/A, reverting to normal PDF output*. Is there any problem with my command, if there so please let me know with a proper solution.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994410/ghostscript-wont-convert-pdf-to-pdf-a-annotation-issue

Comment: That isn't the latest version of Ghostscript (note the date, 2019). The current version is 9.56.1. Without seeing your input file it is impossible to tell why the PDFACompatibilityPolicy isn't being honoured.